# What do you call the sponge part of a cake in Chinese?

Tags: word

Cake usually consists of a sponge that is decorated with chocolate or icing in some way.

The sponge is a very light bread-like substance.

What do you call this sponge in Chinese ?

Comment: As an aside, calling this bit a "sponge" would confuse me and most other English speakers I know. In at least my dialect of American English, this would just be called "the cake" and people who don't want frosting/icing on it would ask for "just the cake" or "the cake without the frosting/icing". Perhaps these descriptions could also be used in Chinese?

Comment: There's also a specific kind of cake called "sponge cake", which is even lighter and fluffier than a typical cake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are mentioning a cake that has no coating outside, it is called 蛋糕胚.

X胚 means an unfinished version of X. Such as 陶胚 is unfinished clay works.

Beause people think the finished cake should have the cream outside. The center part that does not have a coating is considered unfinished. So it is called 蛋糕胚。

Example:

> [6寸基础戚风（蛋糕胚）](https://www.xiachufang.com/recipe/102208654/

*Note: 戚风 is the name of style of the 蛋糕胚 in the link. There are also other styles.*

---

If you are pointing at the "bread" part of a slice of cake, you can just call it 蛋糕 or 蛋糕的部分. Because that is a part that contains egg 蛋. For example,

```
我喜欢蛋糕的部分，很香。但是我不喜欢上面的奶油，太甜了。
I like the "sponge part". it smells so good. 
But I don't like the cream on it. It is too sweet for me.
```

Comment: Great , so if someone is cutting a cake and I want to say that I don't like icing on cakes and to just give me some of the sponge, I can use 蛋糕胚  ?

Comment: @Kantura I just updated the answer because I realize there are to situations. If you want to say "I just want the sponge part". You can say, 我只要蛋糕的部分，不要上面的奶油。or simply 只要蛋糕，不要奶油。

Answer (score 2):

Cake makers may refer to it as 蛋糕胚 (unfinished cake) before the cake is finished. In layman's term, most people would just call it 糕身 (body of the cake) or 淨蛋糕 (plain cake)

Customers would only say the cake 糕身鬆軟 because they never see the unfinished cake

糕身 = cake's body

淨蛋糕 = plain (not decorated or elaborate) cake

蛋糕的部分 = the cake part

*I was from Hong Kong, maybe mainland Chinese would use different words*

Answer (score 0):

Professional way: 戚風蛋糕(Chiffon Cake)、蛋糕體、蛋糕胚

Unprofessional way(like me)：蛋糕裡面的麵包 (the bread part of a cake)